# Strange compiling error on C# string.Join

Tags: c#

In a uwp function, I am calling this:

```
var selectedDates = sender.SelectedDates.Select(p => p.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + p.Date.Day.ToString()).ToArray();
var values = string.Join(", " + (string[])selectedDates);
CalendarViewResultTextBlock.Text = values;
```

But I got an error when compiling them:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join(string, params object[])' and 'string.Join(string, params string[])'

Who knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Bit off topic, but if you used proper variable declarations instead of using `var` you'd see fewer issues.

Comment: You're concating your array to a comma ...

Comment: HUGE TIP, when you call a method like `Join` and type the open bracket a tooltip shows which arguments the method expects. The tooltip also shows method overloads. Always give methods what they expect and you can always Press F12 or Goto Definition to inspect the method signatures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var values = string.Join(", ", (string[]) selectedDates );
```

(Remove the + sign)

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong call. It should be

```
string.Join(", ", array)
```

In your example it's **+** but should be **, **.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation for the error

This expression turns into a string

```
", " +(string[])selectedDates
```

`string.Join` expects a string followed by a array of parameters. By only providing a string, the array of parameters is inferred to be an empty array. This is not the behaviour you're looking for, but also, the compiler has no way of inferring the type of an empty array